# Add hyperlink to hidden bookmark in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, bookmarks, hyperlink, cross-reference, caption

I am manually assembling a list of figures for a large Word document. I originally used the "Table of Figures" feature to generate this automatically from figure captions, but I found that I was unable to get the resulting table to obey the (very particular) formatting requirements I must follow. So I did it by hand. That all worked fine, but now I would like to link each entry in my list of figures to the corresponding figure.

I want to do this using hyperlinks, which almost works - you can hyperlink to a bookmark within the same document, and Word seems to automatically generate a hidden (underscore-prefixed) bookmark for every figure caption. This is what cross-references use internally. Unfortunately, the "insert hyperlink" dialog does not list hidden bookmarks, and unlike the bookmarks dialog, there is no checkbox to toggle displaying these. I don't want to un-hide these bookmarks or create my own bookmarks manually for each figure, because I will export this Word document as a PDF and don't want garbage bookmarks like "_Ref324234324" showing up in PDF readers' navigation pane. I have tried inserting a hyperlink to some visible bookmark in the document, pressing ALT+F9 to edit the field codes, then changing the target of the hyperlink to the desired hidden bookmark, but this has no effect - clicking the modified hyperlink still takes you to wherever the hyperlink originally pointed.

I do not want to use actual cross-references either, because they determine the text that is displayed, and the entire point of my constructing this list of figures by hand was that I needed some of the text to be different from the contents of the captions.

Is there some way I can use a hidden bookmark as a hyperlink target?

Comment: I think you will have to generate bookmarks that are not hidden. Can you give an example of the formatting you need that does not work with the Table of Figures feature? You are making a lot of work for yourself.

Comment: I needed to have it formatted as a numbered list, with hanging indents and a blank line between every entry, with dot leaders that end at a tab stop a specified distance before the page number; I also essentially had to be able to give each entry an arbitrary title that isn't quite what the cross-reference would pick up from the caption. The pure formatting stuff I imagine is possible (I feel like I've gotten hanging indents in a numbered list in the past) but having to tweak the titles makes it a lot of work. I ended up not adding links, but I think you're right that this was a bad approach.